# Can you explain this Typescript snippet?

Tags: typescript

Can you explain this Typescript snippet?

```
interface Validator<T extends Control> {
    (c:T): {[error: string]:any};
 }
```

So it's an interface extending Control, which has a function (method) that accepts the same type of class (generic) as passed into Validator (T), and that method returns a type of an object of ...??? now that part I am confused on:

```
 {[error: string]:any};
```

It's a type of object? any? not sure?!

tx

Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Validator` is an interface with one type parameter, `T`. `T` extends `Control`, so whatever is supplied as `T` must extend `Control`. (See [the language spec for more on this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#361-type-parameter-lists).)

Objects that implement the `Validator` interface are callable (they are a function). When called, `Validator` objects expect one argument of type `T` and return an object. This object can be indexed into with strings which could map to a value of any type. The `[error: string]:any` notation is called [an index signature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.9.4) and is [explained in prose here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-array-types). It essentially just means you can access an object with brackets instead of dot-notation.

Thus an example usage might look something like:

```
const someValidator = getValidatorOfTypeT();
someValidator(objectOfTypeT)["stringKey"] // is of type `any`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  [error: string]:any;
}
```

This is called an *index signature*. It says that when the object is indexed by a string, e.g. `foo["something"]`, the result is of type `any`, and that *all* declared properties of the type are assignable to `any` (though this doesn't mean anything in particular since everything is assignable to `any`).